# Opposite/dual of projection mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, definition

Consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ and, for some $1\leq k\leq n$, the maps
$$\operatorname{pr}_k\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R},\quad(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mapsto x_k,$$
and
$$\operatorname{st}_k\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n, \quad x\mapsto (0,\dots,0,x,0,\dots,0).$$

$\operatorname{pr}_k$ is called projection, so, does $\operatorname{st}_k$ have a name, too?

Comment: They are called insertions.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds reasonable. Do you have a resource? I'd accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: I call them *multiplication by the standard basis vectors*.

Comment: Google "codproduct category theory"

Comment: They are also called injections but these can be confused with monomorphisms.

Comment: @Rahul Yeah, that'd make sense, too, but I'd rather have a name for the mapping that I will, afterwards, identify the multiplication of the standard basis vectors with. Insertions sounds good, thank you both!